# What's the main difference of the feature between StackExchange and Mathoverflow?

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between MSE and MO](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/difference-between-mse-and-mo)

Just as the title said, I want to know what kind of question will be more properly post on StackExchange rather than Mathoverflow, and what kind of question will be more properly for Mathoverflow than StackExchange?

Comment: Look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/41,  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/difference-between-mse-and-mo, and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1533/is-this-a-scraper-site-or-what.

Comment: ok, that's helpful.